# Boot mac from dvd, touchpad not clicking

Tags: macos, boot, touchpad

How come I can't click when I boot my mac from installer DVD? I can move the cursor on the screen but I can't click. How to solve it?

Comment: Neither tap nor pushing down on the trackpad to click work? have you tried a usb mouse?

Comment: neither tap nor pushing. I don't have an usb mouse...

Comment: Tap to click is disabled. If you are actually clicking the track pad, then I'm not sure

Comment: I'm clicking it. I'm in the need of reinstalling the OS but without mouse is a trivial task...

Comment: Then I'd recommend a USB mouse as @user142485 recommended. Converting to comment...